# MFC DLL library conversion to Web API Services

Tags: dll, service, mfc

We have a large MFC library in a DLL that exposes an API to our .net application to any other .net applications running on the same server.  We would like to migrate all of the API calls to Web API Services.  Are there any conversion tools available?  Any tips on efficient migration strategies?

Answer (score 0):

We did this in my windows application. For that we use the C++/CLI.  We create a C++/CLI project and this project will communicate with the MFC dll and our WPF application.  Using this implementation we can communicate with the WPF application and the MFC dll.
Hope this will help you.